# Фамилия Брюллов

Tags: этимология, ономастика

Каково происхождение фамилии художника Карла Брюллова?

Comment: Господ ж, ну одним тыком находится.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Брюллов
Анализ фамилии:
Эта фамилия в 50% случаев имеет русское происхождение, в 5% - украинское, в 10% - белорусское, в 30% приходит из языков народов России (татарского, мордовского, башкирского, бурятского и т. д.), в 5% случаев происходит из болгарского или сербского языков. В любом случае эта фамилия образована от имени, прозвища, рода занятий или места жительства дальнего предка человека по мужской линии. 
Значение, происхождение и история фамилии:
БРЮЛЛОВ
Фамилия немецкого происхождения. Братьям-живописцам Карлу и Александру Брюлло (Brullo) в 1822 г. было вменено высочайшим декретом русское написание Брюллов.(Э)

Comment: Вы все-таки относитесь критически к подобным сайтам.
Вы видели немецкую фамилию Brulleau?

И по поводу происхождения:
Фамилия:
**ТрДрБрХрщенский**
Результаты поиска:
Родственные узлы: Да
Генеалогия: Нет
Письма из архивов: Да
Награды и медали: Вероятно
Дворянство на Руси: Нет
Купеческий архив: Нет
**Родственники: Более 22**
~~~~~~

Comment: Смешно....

Comment: А мне грустно, что приняли ответ с сайтай, где боты генерируют псевдоаналитическую тарабарщину.

Comment: Это да....

Answer (score 3):

*Карл Брюллов родился 12 (23) декабря 1799 года в Санкт-Петербурге, в семье академика, резчика по дереву и гравёра французского происхождения Павла Ивановича Брюлло (Brulleau, 1760—1833) и его супруги Марии Ивановны Шредер (Schroeder), имевшей немецкие корни.*
©Вики

Comment: Граммар-наци негодуют. Скорее не Шредер, а Шрёдер. Ср. с Гёте (Goethe) или Шрёдингер.

Comment: Шрёдер, конечно. Но это не предмет обсуждения в этой теме.